# aws mysql database(Amazon RDS) or mongodb?

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, mobile-development, mongodb-atlas

I am making an e-commerce app using flutter for frontend, and have decided to choose node js for making API, my doubt is should I use AWS Rds (environment to run MySQL database), or should I use MongoDB atlas?

I am not able to understand which is better, as both MongoDB cloud and AWS Rds are also paid I am unable to decide which one to choose. According, to what I searched and found, MongoDB is cheaper than AWS Rds, but MongoDB requires more maintenance. How much maintenance is actually required and which is better?  Please help !!

Also, what are the other options for backend storage if I don't use the cloud??

Comment: Do you need an SQL or a NoSQL database?

Comment: Both are ok actually. One issue that I was facing with MYSQL was that I needed to fetch the subproduct of every product, and I needed to fetch products in 4 screens, so there is a lot of fetching that I needed to do, and the workaround for that would be to stringify the subproduct details and store them in a field of product table. But, I am not sure, if that is a good practice. Also, I am not sure, if that could create any trouble in the future.

Comment: Whereas the subproduct details can be stored as an array of objects in one of the product fields in MongoDB, and so fetching it is a lot easier in MongoDB. Other than that, all things are fine, and I can have SQL or NoSQL database. :)

Comment: So, that is I am in a state of confusion, please help.